# Difference between Positioned and Transform.translate in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

Both can offset a widget. What should be used?

I used these inside a stack:

```
Transform.translate(
   offset: Offset(0.0,29),
   child: ElevatedButton(
             onPressed: (){},
             child: Text("Click me"),
          ),
)
```

```
Positioned(
   child: ElevatedButton(
             onPressed: (){},
             child: Text("Click me"),
   ),
   bottom: -29,
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Positioned Widget`

- `child widget` can be positioned in relation to the stack.
- you need to  utilise the top, bottom, left, and right properties to specify the widget's position when utilising the position property.

`Transform.translate`

- `child widget` can be translated by a certain amount using the `offset` attribute which is used to define the amount of translation.

Depending on your use case, you may use one of these widgets in your sample code. Use `Positioned` if you wish to place the widget in relation to the stack. Use `Transform.translate` if you wish to translate the widget by a specific amount.

Further refer:

- Positioned: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html
- Transform.translate: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html